# Salesforce to Salesforce ETL - Automatic Data Transfers

Tags: migration-tool, etl

My team is working on migrating to a new Org, from our previous Org. However, we need to use both and have the same data in both, as we will be rolling out clients in batches into the new Org, before we completely migrate.

I'm looking for an ETL tool that will allow for automatic data migration depending on predefined criteria. If an event happens in the Old Org it should be migrated to the new Org. Vice Versa, if something is updated in the New Org, the data should be transferred to the Old Org.

Does anyone know of a tool that would allow for this type of customization in an ETL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using [Talend](http://www.talend.com/download) for some complex migrations as you can build some amazing stuff there. It also has free version which I was using. For the migration that you would like to do you might need to define an `external Id` for your records as their actual Ids will change between orgs and you can update them based on that Id and on `lastModifiedDate`. However you'll need to schedule this integration to run say each 1 hour and you can run into situation like that:

Say you have account A

1. It was modified 12:00 on your first org
2. The same Account was modified 12:02 in your second org

As a result of such integration you will have Account A on both orgs as it was on your second org at 12:02 and changes made on your first org at 12:00 will be lost. To handle this you need to check every field each time and that might be too complicated... It would be good if your moved clients can use only new org after they have been moved, then you will don't need to check all the fields just update the old one from the new for them.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! It would be much more convenient, if we didn't have to migrate data between both orgs, but the way our system and company is structured, it isn't possible to make this happen. However, I will check out Talentd.